# What's a good toString method for a deftype'd object in clojure

Tags: clojure, instantiation, tostring, deftype

```
(deftype Bag [state]
   Object
     (toString [bag]
       (str "Bag???" state)))
```

I want the toString to look something like

```
clojure.core=> (def b (Bag. {:apples 1 :bannanas 4}))
#'clojure.core/b
clojure.core=> (str b)
"BAG: {:apples 1 :bannanas 4}"
```

What is a nice clojurey way of representing that information?
Is

```
"Bag/{:k :v}"
```

better?  How does the community do you call your toStrings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is for `deftype`.

```
user=> (deftype Bag [state] 
         Object 
         (toString [_] 
           (str "BAG: " (pr-str state))))
user.Bag
user=> (def b (Bag. {:apples 1 :bannanas 4}))
#'user/b
user=> (str b)
"BAG: {:bannanas 4, :apples 1}"
```

Answer (score 8):

Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, the simplest way is to use `defrecord`:

```
user=> (defrecord Bag [state])
user.Bag
user=> (def b (Bag. :foo))
#'user/b
user=> b
#:user.Bag{:state :foo}
```

Though what you see above is from `pr`, not `str`:

```
user=> (str b)
"user.Bag@53e935f4"
user=> (prn b)
#:user.Bag{:state :foo}
nil
```

So we just make a change:

```
user=> (defrecord Bag [state]
         Object
         (toString [bag] (pr-str bag)))
user.Bag
user=> (def b (Bag. :foo))
#'user/b
user=> (str b)
"#:user.Bag{:state :foo}"
user=> (.toString b)
"#:user.Bag{:state :foo}"
```

Now, if the above is not suitable, then next option would be to add a new method to the `print-method` multi-method.  Google around for details on that.

Aside:  Using `defrecord` should generally be preferred over `deftype` unless you're doing something very low-level.

Comment: Define low level.  I'm trying to create new collection types (bags and multimaps).  When do you use defrecord or deftype and why?

Comment: Using this method with deftype yields a java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Yes, if you're creating new collection type, deftype is probably correct, whereas defrecord is more appropriate when needing something like a struct of some domain data.